# Find out if SEXP is a linked to variable in R

Tags: c++, r, rinside

I am using **RInside** library to run embed **R** inside C++ application. After parsing R command such as:

```
std::string command = "a <- 5"
const SEXP res = mRSession->parseEval( command);
```

I would like to know if the `res` is `SEXP` that is an R variable (the `command` actually comes from GUI frontend). I understand that it is somehow connected to knowing if there is `SYMSXP` inside the `SEXP`. But the actual structure of `SEXP` is kind of a mystery.

The overall goal is to mimic printing in console in RStudio, where `SEXP` values that are not linked to R variables are printed, while R variables are not printed. So command `a <- 5` would not print outcome, but `5+3` would print.

I tested various functions from `<RInternals.h>` but none of them provided the result that I am looking for. But the main issue most likely is that I am actually looking at data of `SEXP` instead of its structure.

Comment: The problem is that the _returned value_ of `a <- 5` is 5 (try `print(a <- 5)` in the R console. You can't just use the `SEXPTYPE` to determine what a line of R code will print to the console, because that depends on the specific printing method of the object. Perhaps you should use `capture.output` or similar if you want to emulate the exact R output.

Comment: It's not that R somehow does something special for assignment, it's that the `<-` function wraps it output with `invisible()` so nothing prints by default. You can use `invisible()` with other functions as well. When you evaluate you should always just get an SEXP back. You won't know where it came from unless you parse the input yourself.

Comment: I am fairly sure I have done that by asking `exists()` in R (via the RInside framework; I think there may even be an example in `inst/examples/standard`).  And/or use the various `ls*` functions.  R lets you query _its_ envirnment and methinks that is what you want here.